# Unable to create a new staff using service in mindBody API

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, loopback, mindbody

I am creating a staff using mingBody API. My response status get success but staff not created. 
My code looks like this:

```
var mboFactory = require('mbo-api');
mboFactory.setSourceCredentials("xxxx", "xxxxx");
mboFactory.setApiKey("xxxxx")
mboFactory.createStaffServiceAsync()
    .then(function (staffService) {
        staffService.setUserCredentials('xxx', 'xxx', xxx)
        var data = {
            HomePhone: '9898426325',
            State: 'NY',
            Country: 'US',
            Name: 'test',
            FirstName: 'test',
            LastName: 'testing',
            Bio: 'aka The RockDo you smell what he is cooking?',
            isMale: false,
            email:"test@test.com",
            password:"@123test123456"
        }
        staffService.AddOrUpdateStaff({UpdateAction: "AddNew", Test: true, Staff: data}).then(function (dataa) {
            console.log(dataa);
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
    });
```

And the result is bellow:

```
{
    Status: 'Success',
    ErrorCode: 200,
    XMLDetail: 'Full',
    ResultCount: 0,
    CurrentPageIndex: 0,
    TotalPageCount: 0,
    Staff: null 
} 
{ 
    ResultCount: 0, Staff: null
}
```